# playwright disable caching of webpage so I can fetch new elements after scrolling down

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, playwright

I'm using playwright (Firefox browser) to scrape some websites. Many of the websites load more content when I scroll down the page. The problem is that the new content loaded is not being picked up by the **await page.$$("")** methods.

But If I do a **document.querySelectorAll("")** on the console after the scroll, then I am able to get the newer content as well.

I see that puppeteer has a setting **page.setCacheEnabled(enabled)** that allows for disabling cache, but I can't find a similar thing in playwright.

Answer (score 5):

You are quite correct that there is no method like `setCacheEnabled` in playwright. One workaround is to set up a route for all requests:

```js
page.route('**', route => route.continue());
```

You can see [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-route) that:

> Enabling routing disables http cache.

Which should accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @Nico-mee. I saw that earlier and did not try it until you suggested it. Even though the docs says that it "disables http cache", it did not resolve my issue. After scrolling the page, I see new content being loaded (headless=false) but when the playwright tries  to fetch all items - existing and newer ones, it still only has older items and none of the new ones. So it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/pull/1231), to avoid cache use a [browserContext](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext)

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue where Playwright 'remembers' the state of the browser from one session to another. The workaround that worked for us was to delete the `test-data-dir` directory before running the script.

[image: test-data-dir]

playwright creates this directory once you run it. So, we have this script defined in our `package.json`

```
"cleanup:chrome": "rm -rf ./path/to/test-data-dir/* || true",
```

And then run playwright as usual